# expected activation_8 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I know there have other posts on this subject/error but I cannot figure out how to adapt them to my code.  I might just need another set of eyes to look at my code to find where I am going wrong.  I apologize for the length.

I am working on an image recognition project.

First I import the libraries:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dropout
from keras import backend as K
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import random
import pickle
import cv2
import os
```

Next, I instantiate my CNN model:

```
class SmallVGGNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)
        chanDim = -1


        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)
            chanDim = 1


        # CONV => RELU => POOL layer set
        model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",
            input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))



        # (CONV => RELU) * 2 => POOL layer set
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))


        # (CONV => RELU) * 3 => POOL layer set
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))


        # first (and only) set of FC => RELU layers
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(512))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))

        # softmax classifier
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

        # return the constructed network architecture
        return model
```

Gathered and processed my images:

```
data = []
labels = []

# grab the image paths and randomly shuffle them
shiba_path = sorted(list(paths.list_images('../downloads/shiba')))
fox_path = sorted(list(paths.list_images('../downloads/fox')))
combine_path = [shiba_path,fox_path]
random.seed(42)

# loop over the input data dictionaries
for path in combine_path:
    path = random.shuffle(path)

# loop over the input images
for imagePaths in combine_path:
    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        try:
            # load the image, resize the image to be 32x32 pixels (ignoring
            # aspect ratio), flatten the image into 32x32x3=3072 pixel image
            # into a list, and store the image in the data list
            image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
            image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))
            data.append(image)

            # extract the class label from the image path and update the
            # labels list
            label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2].split('/')[-1]
            labels.append(label)
        except:
            pass
```

```
# scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)
```

Run my model:

```
# partition the data into training and testing splits using 75% of
# the data for training and the remaining 25% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data,
    labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# convert the labels from integers to vectors
lb = LabelBinarizer()
trainY = lb.fit_transform(trainY)
testY = lb.transform(testY)
```

`trainY` has a shape of `(1429,1)` and `trainX` has shape of `(1429, 64, 64, 3)`

```
# construct the image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

# initialize our VGG-like Convolutional Neural Network
model = SmallVGGNet.build(width=64, height=64, depth=3,
    classes=len(lb.classes_))
```

The problem comes in the next step.

```
# initialize our initial learning rate, # of epochs to train for,
# and batch size
INIT_LR = 0.01
EPOCHS = 20
BS = 32

# initialize the model and optimizer
print("[INFO] training network...")
opt = SGD(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the network
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(testX, testY), steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)
```

This step generates

> > Error when checking target: expected activation_8 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Where am I going wrong?  What am I doing that it is expecting my Y to have a shape of 2?  Should it have a shape of 1 or should it be 2?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate the error, the issue was in the last activation layer and loss function.

Since you are already converting the target variable to One-Hot encoded using `LabelBinarizer`, your target data looks something like this, which includes both the classes.

```
array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0]])
```

In the output layer, instead of giving number of classess as input, give 1, since it outputs only a single value , and change the loss function from `categorical_crossentropy` to `binary_crossentropy`

Below is the modified block.

```
# softmax classifier
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

Changing loss function to this:

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])
```

This will resolve your issue, Happy Learning!

**Edit 1:**

Providing the model summary.

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 64, 64, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 64, 64, 32)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 32, 32, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 32, 32, 64)        256       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 16, 16, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 16, 16, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (Batch (None, 16, 16, 128)       512       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 8192)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               4194816   
_________________________________________________________________
activation_7 (Activation)    (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (Batch (None, 512)               2048      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_8 (Activation)    (None, 1)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 4,624,897
Trainable params: 4,622,785
Non-trainable params: 2,112
```

Comment: @Jerel - If your issue is resolved using above solution, please accept and upvote the answer, Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I made the changes you recommended but I am getting a new error ```ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (64, 64, 2) but got array with shape (64, 64, 3)```  It looks like in the step which I gather and pre-process my images it is creating a 3 by array instead of a 2 by.  The shape of ```trainX``` is still ```(1429, 64, 64, 3)```.  How do I fix this?  Thank you again.

Comment: @Jerel - I have used your complete code with my data and with the above-mentioned modifications. I haven't faced any errors. Still, I'm editing the answer with the model summary. You can compare and let me know if there is any difference.

Comment: When I ran a summary on the model all the information is the same as what you have except for the first line:

```conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 64, 32)        608```

Should the shape of my `trainX` be `(1429, 64, 64, 3)` or `(1429, 64, 64, 2)`?

Comment: Your `trainX` shape should be `(1429, 64, 64, 3)`  and you should give `model = SmallVGGNet.build(width=64, height=64, depth=3,
    classes=len(lb.classes_))` , if you give depth as 2, you will get the error which you are getting above.